# Get keys of namespace and access namespace members with brackets

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can i import all types from a file without changing it, like the `test.ts` file below, and access them via the bracket syntax?

test.ts

```
export type TEST1 = 'test1'
export type TEST2 = 'test2'
export type TEST3 = 'test3'
export type TEST4 = 'test4'
```

index.ts

```
import type * as T from './test'

const a: T.TEST1 = 'test1' // what i can do
type B = 'TEST2' | 'TEST3' // subset of available types in test.ts
const b: T[B] = 'test2' // what i want to do
```

Comment: `T` is a namespace. You can't really... Can I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: @catgirlkelly i need to acces types generated by amplify/graphQL to use them in an api wrapper function so that i can have types based on the parameters that i pass to the wrapper, i kind of solved it by putting all types into an interface but i would like to automate the process.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this with namespaces. You could open an issue on their GitHub and ask for them to generate the interface as well? As an option or something.

Comment: @catgirlkelly maybe or i could just write a script that does that, i was/am interested if its possible to do it with the builtin import/export.

Comment: Seems it isn't possible https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25574

Answer (score 2):

At first glance at the docs it may seem like this is not possible but I think I figured it out. For this specific scenario you've shown in your example where the types are string literals, you could use a combination of an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like this:

`test.ts`

```
type TYPES = 'test1' | 'test2' | 'test3' | 'test4';

type MAPPED = {
  [key in TYPES]: TYPES;
}

type TYPE = {
  TEST1: 'test1',
  TEST2: 'test2',
  TEST3: 'test3',
  TEST4: 'test4'
}

type T = MAPPED & TYPE;

export default T;
```

`index.ts`

```
import type T from './test';

type b = 'TEST2' | 'TEST3';
const b: T[b] = 'test1';
```

The second line will show the error:

> Type '"test1"' is not assignable to type '"test2" | "test3"'. Did you
> mean '"test2"'?

Which proves that this is working as intended.

Comment: But what about `export const test1 = "test1";` and the like...?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand the question. @Syler could definitely use regular old string constants but since they specifically asked for how to do this with types that is why I tried to find this (admittedly clunky) solution. The benefit of this being that the type information doesn't get included in the compiled JS.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i probably have not made i clear enough in the question, the problem is that i don't have access to `test.ts`, as pointed by @Валера Битковский, its probably not possible to do it in typescript at the moment.

Comment: Ok I see now, yes then definitely not possible :( you could create something that maybe takes the generated `test.ts` and then converts it to the format I showed but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @niiyeboah i already have, i created a script that creates an interface in an new file with all types as properties.